# Old OS still trying to boot after being removed using msconfig

Tags: windows-7, boot, operating-systems

I had two different copies of Windows 7 on my SSD. I deleted the one I did not want and removed it from my boot order using msconfig, but every time I restart it says:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might have caused the issue.
```

but if I hit Enter or Esc, it will boot normally. How do Ii get it to stop trying to boot that old deleted OS?

Comment: Can you provide a pic of your Disk Management screen?

Comment: you could try this tool to see what's stored in boot config: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click your `Computer` icon (either on desktop or in the start-menu). Click `Advanced System Settings` on the left navigation tab. Go to the `Advanced` tab on the top. Then in `Startup and Recovery`, click `Advanced`. There, choose your new OS as the default OS, and make sure the boot menu isn't displayed.

[image: Glee is awesome!]

Hope that helped!

Comment: did that, there is only one listed and yet there is a non listed broken os that tries to boot first.

Answer (score 0):

First or initial system BCD used is stored on active partition.

After selecting unsuccesful boot entry or escaping from advanced boot options the drive specified for bootmgr in the initial BCD is used as base for "second" system BCD.

Initial and "second BCD" could be the same BCD or two different BCD's stored on different partitions depending on what is specified in drive element of bootmgr.

You can use bcdedit or [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) to view and edit complete BCD contents.